# How do I stop Visual web developer from copying the attributes of a div to its closing tag?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

When I

> Right click -> Surround with -> html -> div

Everything I type after the word div gets copied by VWD to its closing tag. How do I stop it? (And why is it doing that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Known bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/582524/asp-net-surround-with-problem-in-html-source-code

But can use `divc` instead.